# pycaffe get gradients/weights/biases

Tags: python, deep-learning, pycaffe

So I have initialized a caffe.Net object with

```
network = caffe.Net('path/to/lenet.prototxt', caffe.TEST)
```

and I want to get activation, weights, biases, gradients for each layer with parameters. My current approach is to do a `step(100)` to go through 100 iterations and then look at every layer:

```
        for layer_name in network._layer_names: 
            if layer_name in network.params:
                x = layer_name
                output = np.array(network.blobs[x].data)
                weight = np.array(network.params[x][0].data)
                bias = np.array(network.params[x][1].data)
```

this should give me the activation, the weights and biases of each layer. Then I save them. No idea for the gradients though.

Is this approach for weights/biases/activation the right one?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of .data use .diff

> #### Implementation Details
>
> As we are often interested in the values as well as the gradients of the blob, a Blob stores two chunks of memories, data and diff. The former is the normal data that we pass along, and the latter is the gradient computed by the network.

http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/net_layer_blob.html

Note that these will be initialized to zero, unless you have run some training steps.